# How to create custom blocks

Tags: block-types, blocks

We would like to create custom blocks. Is it possible to create custom blocks? if yes, do you have a good tutorial?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're trying to accomplish?  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "custom blocks".

Comment: When a user creates a post, they have an option to add more Blocks (Block Types?), like heading, text, pull quote, image, etc.. An example of a custom block could be a image carousel, or a text with a floating image on the right.  -- thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're referring to [Matrix](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields) block types.  You can create additional block types for a Matrix field, or edit existing ones by going to that Matrix's [field settings](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields#settings) under `Settings->Fields->(your matrix field)` in the control panel.

Comment: Thanks, makes totally sense. Before my brain was wired to look for Blocks and not Matrix, so I overlooked Matrix over and over.